# Hazelcast "Others" taking 90% of memory

Tags: caching, hazelcast

We are using Hazelcast (v4.2) as a cache solution. We are using only IMap data structure to store the data.

In Management Center, we are seeing the Map memory is less than 5% and "Others" is taking upto 90% of the heap memory. The value for Others fluctuates between 50 and 90.

We are not able to understand what is it taking this much memory. This sometimes brings down the cluster also, when it reaches 100%.

Has someone faced similar issue?

Comment: The other area shows the heap memory used by all entities subtracted by the heap memory used by the map. Do you use hazelcast as the embedded mode in your application? If so,  your application consumes %90 heap size.

Comment: @İlkerKorkut We are using client server setup. A mentioned in the post, we are not using any other entities but IMap. I am not able to understand whats getting stored as "Others".

Comment: @shahidbits How many entities do you store in IMap? What's single entity size? How much memory is your single hz node  granted? How many nodes are there in cluster? How many replicas have you configured?